# Which function will be called if mmap() without a fd (use MAP_ANONYMOUS)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

If I `mmap()` from a device, for example: `/dev/mem`.

```
fbfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
dataBuffer = (char *)mmap(0, 
                          FILESIZE, 
                          PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                          MAP_SHARED, 
                          fbfd, 
                          0);
```

Then I can see the actual function do `remap_pfn_range` is `mmap_mem()`, which is `f_op->mmap` of `/dev/mem` I think.

But if I `mmap()` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and without fd, which function will be call to do `remap_pfn_range`?

```
    dataBuffer = (char *)mmap(0, 
                              FILESIZE, 
                              PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                              MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 
                              0, 
                              0);
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I find the answer...

There is no fd, so no `f_op->mmap`.

If a `mmap()` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `MAP_SHARED`, it will be handle by `shmem_zero_setup()`, setup a shared anonymous mapping, and also prepare a `vma` for `do_mmap_pgoff()`.